# Spring-ws on Weblogic: MessageDispatcherServlet doesn't have a default constructor

Tags: weblogic-10.x, spring-ws

I'm trying to deploy a war containing spring webservices. But I am getting a weird error like this:

```
following error weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "spring-ws" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "myApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet class: 'org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet' doesn't have a default constructor
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:261)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1976)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1950)
```

I've tried giving a default constructor in the endpoint class.

Below are the steps which I followed:

1. `web.xml` has this entry:

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
           <param-value>true</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
2. web-inf folder has `spring-ws-servlet.xml` file which has the entries for component scan, enabling the annotations and the wsdl entry like this:

   ```
   <sws:static-wsdl id="MyService" 
        location="classpath:/services/myService/1.0/MyService.wsdl" />
   ```

Please let me know if I'm missing anything here....

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the jar files Weblogic is using to initialize the Spring classes and those expected to be used are in conflict.

To force the Weblogic container to use the jar files bundled with the war file you have to specify a **WEB-INF/weblogic.xml** file with the following content

```
<weblogic-web-app>
<container-descriptor>
<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

see [this thread](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/7349-problems-deploying-app-on-weblogic-8-1-sp4)